# How to make IDLE automatically import modules at start?

Tags: python, python-import, python-idle, autostart

Often when I am using the IDLE shell I import the `pickle` module. Is it possible to make it automatically import `pickle` when I start it?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: Not a duplicate, since that solution is for the Python shell, not idle. These solutions don't work for idle.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: I am a CPython core developer and currently the main Idle developer. Carpetsmoker is correct; this is not a duplicate.  User code is *not* executed in the __main__ module. That is why the normal python solutions to execute code in the __main__ module are useless.  Indeed, they could even be dangerous in the sense of disabling Idle.  User code is instead exec-ed in a separate namespace designed to simulate __main__.  So separate means are required to affect the environment for user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-c` or -`r` argument:

From `idle -h`:

```
-c cmd     run the command in a shell, or
-r file    run script from file
```

For example:

```
idle -c 'import pickle, sys'
```

Or:

```
idle -r ~/my_startup.py
```

Where `my_startup.py` might contain:

```
import pickle, sys
```

You can either create a shell alias to always use this, or create a separate script; the procedure for this differs depending on your OS and shell.

Comment: According to my test using -c "import itertools", the effect disappears when the shell is restarted, as when a file is run from the editor.  I have an idea to partly fix this, by running files in a separate process and leaving the interactive shell alone, but that is at best in the future.